# Existence of $g \in H(A)$ such that $f=g'$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Given that $A=\{z:r<|z|<R\}$, where $r<1<R$. Suppose that $f \in H(A)$ satisfies
\begin{equation*}
\int_\Gamma f(z) dz=0,
\end{equation*} where $\Gamma$ is the positively oriented unit circle. Prove that there exists a $g \in H(A)$ such that $f=g'$. How do I start to prove it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are your ideas?

Comment: @ Mushu Nrek, I tried to start from its Laurent series, but it seems it is not a right way. I also tried to define $F(z)=\int_{\Gamma(z)} f(z) dz$, where $\Gamma(z)$ is any path in $A$ from a fixed point $z_0$ in $A$ to $z \in A$. However, I can't show that $F$ is well-defined.

Comment: You are on the right track with the second idea! What do you need to show to get that $F$ is well-defined?

Comment: I have to show that $F$ does not depend on the choice of the path $\Gamma(z)$.

Comment: Exactly. So take two such paths $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$. And if you concatenate them, you get a new path $\Gamma$ which goes from $z_0$ to $z_0$. And the only thing you need to prove is that the integral along $\Gamma$ is zero.

Comment: @ Mushu Nrek Yes, you are right, but I stuck on the use of the given integral on this. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: You surely have seen that the value of a curve integral does not change if the curve it moved continuously? (Invariance under homotopy or something like this.)

Answer (score 1):

If the Laurent series in the annulus is $f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n z^n$, the condition on the integral tells you $a_{-1} = 0$.  Note that if $n \ne -1$, $\int z^n\; dz = z^{n+1}/(n+1)$.  So you can define the antiderivative by a Laurent series.